# Python Django Multi Level Join Query

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-queryset, django-serializer

**Task Details**
I am working on creating a custom API to fetch data from three tables, based on provided key info.

**Background**
To elaborate, I've three data tables - Client, Account and Client_accounts and their structure looks like this:

```
Client
    ID           (Integer)       Primary Key
    display_name (varchar)

Accounts
    ID           (Integer)       Primary Key
    nickname     (varchar)   

Client_Accounts
    Client_ID    (Integer)       Foreign Key -> ID from client table   
    Account_ID   (Integer)       Foreign Key -> ID from accounts table
```

In intend to pass a client ID to my API and want to fetch all the accounts (and accounts names) owned by that client.

The SQL query that I am trying to replicate looks like this:

```
select
    cl.id as client_id,
    cl.display_name,
    ac.id as account_id,
    ac.nickname as account_name
from
    datahub_clients         cl
    join
    datahub_client_accounts cl_ac
    on 
        cl.id=cl_ac.client_id
    join    
    datahub_accounts        ac
    on 
        cl_ac.account_id=ac.id
where
    cl.id=15
;
```

**Done so far**
This is what I used to fetch the the accounts for a client:

```
##### For endpoint - get_client_name
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
@permission_classes((AllowAny,))
def get_client_name(request):
    try:
        if request.method == 'GET':   
            list_of_account_ids = Client_Accounts.objects.filter(client_id=request.GET['id']).values_list('account')
            needed_accounts = Accounts.objects.filter(id__in=list_of_account_ids).values('id','nickname')

            return Response({'requested client id':request.GET['id'],'identified client name': 'detailed info to go here'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

        else:
          return Response({'status':'error','message': 'Facepalm moment!'}, status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
```

**Problem Statement**

1) In the code above, I was able to pull the relevant accounts for a client_id, however, I can only print the details from account table. How do I put client information as well in the output (client_id, nickname - as shown in the SQL query)

2) What is the django replacement for SQL 'old_field_name AS some_new_name'? In the data tables shown above, both the account and client tables have an 'ID' column. I want to put them both together in the same JSON output and to be able to distinguish between then, I would want to rename them.

3) At this point, my queryset has field members from multiple models. How do I serialize them? I understand that I need to write a custom serializer, which would be based on the two models (for the example show above). I am confused about what to specify in the model= section and meta: section.

Comment: I don't have a concrete answer for you right now but this looks like a really good case for Django's `ManyToManyField`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/. It will generate a through table for you - you can also specify a custom through table. The features that Django provides will be much better if you're using the OOTB field instead of using a custom implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs @JamieCounsell. I read through the docs and still couldn't make a headway. Still looking at the a concise way to get the results. Also I am more curious about understanding the object linking since I'd eventually want to do summarizations.